# SQL Server full join without ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got two sql tables(ITEM_A, ITEM_B) containing same fields (ITEM,Designation).

ITEMA_A

```
001 LaptopA1
001 LaptopA2
001 LaptopA3
002 DesktopA1
002 DesktopA2
003 MouseA1
003 MouseA2
```

ITEM_B

```
001 LaptopB1
001 LaptopB2
002 DesktopB1
002 DesktopB2
002 DesktopB3
002 DesktopB4
003 MouseB1
003 MouseB2
003 MouseB3
```

Here is the query I made:

```
SELECT ITEM,Designation1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY Designation1) 'row'
INTO #ITM_A
FROM ITM_A




SELECT ITEM,Designation2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY Designation2) 'row'
INTO #ITM_B
FROM ITM_B;


SELECT A.ITEM,A.Designation1,B.ITEM,B.Designation2 
FROM #ITM_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN  #ITM_B B ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM AND A.row = B.row
```

Here is the result I get:

```
001  LaptopA1     001   LaptopB1
001 LaptopA2      001   LaptopB2
001 LaptopA3      NULL  NULL
002 DesktopA1     002   DesktopB1
002 DesktopA2     002   DesktopB2
003 MouseA1       003   MouseB1
003 MouseA2       003   MouseB2
NULL    NULL      002   DesktopB3
NULL    NULL      002   DesktopB4
NULL    NULL      003   MouseB3
```

I need to display it that way:

```
001 LaptopA1    001 LaptopB1
001 LaptopA2    001 LaptopB2
001 LaptopA3    NULL    NULL
002 DesktopA1   002 DesktopB1
002 DesktopA2   002 DesktopB2
NULL    NULL    002 DesktopB3
NULL    NULL    002 DesktopB4
003 MouseA1     003 MouseB1
003 MouseA2     003 MouseB2
NULL   NULL     003 MouseB3
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on `without ordering`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add order by:

```
SELECT A.ITEM,A.Designation1,B.ITEM,B.Designation2 
FROM #ITM_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN  #ITM_B B ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM AND A.row = B.row 
order by isnull(A.ITEM,B.ITEM)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the required output, you just need to add:
  `ORDER BY ISNULL(A.ITEM,B.ITEM)` at the end of your query.